# GPO settings for IE7 not sticking

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, internet-explorer

Setup: Running Windows Server 2008 Standard with SP2. Function levels are both set to 2008.

I'm having issues setting IE7 security settings and having them stick. When I go to `User Configuration` > `Preferences` > `Control Panel Settings` > `Internet Settings`. I setup an Internet Explorer 7 setting. I'm setting up a trusted zone. I'm setting the following settings to **Enabled**.

- Binary and script behaviors
- Download signed ActiveX controls
- Download unsigned ActiveX controls
- Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting
- Run ActiveX controls and plug-ins
- Script ActiveX controls marked as safe for scripting

I set that and close out of the Group Policy. When I go back into it, they go back to the same setting I had just changed them from.

Could anyone help explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you are using the F5-F8 keys to save the relevant parts of the preference correctly. Please see http://blogs.technet.com/b/grouppolicy/archive/2008/10/13/red-green-gp-preferences-doesn-t-work-even-though-the-policy-applied-and-after-gpupdate-force.aspx if it helps.

Comment: I like what you found here. Let me see what I can do on Monday with this and get back to you!